# Textbox_change() event only on keyboard input

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function FtoC(ByVal Temp As Variant) As Variant
FtoC = Round((Temp - 32) * 5 / 9, 1)
End Function
Function CtoF(ByVal Temp As Variant) As Variant
CtoF = Round(Temp * 9 / 5 + 32, 1)
End Function

Private Sub Temp_F_Change()
If Temp_F <> "" Then Temp_C = FtoC(Temp_F)
End Sub
Private Sub Temp_C_Change()
If Temp_C <> "" Then Temp_F = CtoF(Temp_C)
End Sub
```

I have the above functions/subs for a little project to learn/sharpen my VBA skills.  The logic is all fine and dandy.  However, ideally I would only like the textbox_change event to only run if the change was due to a keyboard input (or a not sub output).  A working example would be starting from blanks for each if I input 78 to Temp_F then it converts to 25.6 outputs it to Temp_C.  Temp_C has now changed and it then converts 25.6 to 78.1 and outputs it to Temp_F, then of course temp_f has changed and it converts it to 25.6 which is not a change bringing both subs to their end points.  Ideally i would like for it to take 78F convert to 25.6C and for the form to recognize that the Temp_C field change was due to a sub output(or not due to a keyboard input) and exit the temp_c_change() sub Is this even possible with VBA, if so how simple/complex is it?  I tooled around with the idea of using a counter that is reset by a keypress event but my scripting skills aren't good enough to make it work.  I thank you guys in advance and apologize that my question is beneath the talent that I've witnessed searching this site for answers before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for something this small you could use a worksheet_change event that first checks the target cell to see if either of the two temperature cells changed (assuming they do not move around the sheet - if they do, consider a named range).  If either of those cells changed, then create the appropriate conversion formula as a string and put it in the other cell.

My apologies, I just noticed that you are working with a textbox event and not a worksheet event.

What happens to the data after it is converted?  Does it go into a cell or get plugged into another function/sub?  Right now, your code will just perform a calculation but doesn't show it or do anything else with it.  Maybe you need to approach it from whatever that happens next.

Comment: Just takes the input from 1 text box does the conversion and outputs it to the other.  At this point I have no real purpose for it.  I was just dabbling to continue improving on my skills and i give myself little scripting challenges.  honestly if it comes down to it ill just make the conversion button driven.  on a separate note if you know of a good site to give me little projects to improve with that would be awesome too.

Comment: Your question got me monkeying around with what you are doing and I see now the problem you are facing with this.  It is a rather frustrating puzzle, is it not?  I am thinking that VBA is not the appropriate tool for doing something like that.  Kind of like fixing a watch with a pipe wrench.  If you did want to create a userform that works similar to what you are proposing, I think you can create dynamic text that changes as you enter new data in the textbox, but just not the companion textbox.  You would need two input boxes and two different labels that would update when the boxes change.